# React-native: Bad response when using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have this code in a new React-Native project:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var url19='http://e-twow.ro/gps/verifica_senzor.php?qr_code=RY7U2'
            fetch(url19)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    console.log("EEEEEEEEEEE"+responseJson.sensor+responseJson.charger);
                })
  }
```

In console I have this:

```
ReactNativeJS: EEEEEEEEEEE11
```

When I paste the url in  browser i have:

```
{"charger":"0","sensor":"0"}
```

Please, help!

Comment: Your console.log should be `console.log(\`EEEEEEEEEEE${responseJson.sensor}${responseJson.charger}\`)` concatenating numbers can have strange results

Comment: Also, template strings are great any more people should know about them.

Comment: I also tried to use this values(responseJson.sensor,responseJson.charger)  in app but the fetch is always wrong.

Comment: just responseJson result?

Comment: @Andrew Those look like strings to me. When you log the parameter what do you see?

Comment: Everything seems good to me - proper result in my console (using ``+`` concat like you). Could you provide us more details?

Comment: @fard same for me when I tested it I get the expected result. Using concatenation and using ES6 Template Strings

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah you’re right that was a slip. However what I’ve suggested won’t cause a problem . I just avoid concatenation, as it helps to avoid problems.

Comment: @Andrew Agreed.

Comment: @Andrew can you share the working code?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/fetch-example) showing it working. It works with both concatenating and with template strings (I would also choose template strings over concatenating)

Comment: Thank you all guys! After cleaning my phone cache everything works well. The problem was the cache.